# How to start multiple node scripts with PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I want to run these pm2 tasks:

```
"pm2-frontend": "pm2 start --name frontend npm -- start",
"pm2-storybook": "pm2 start --name storybook npm -- storybook"
```

Which should run these two `package.json` scripts:

```
"storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
"start": "next start"
```

But, this only seems to start the `start` script. Is there a way to target scripts with another name than `start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the word `run` before you run scripts other than start.
`Start` is a default script name so you can run it with `npm start` but storybook is not a default script so you gotta use `npm run storybook`